# How can I add a VCard to contacts with Xamarin(Android)?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-intent, contacts

1.With this method I can transfer a Vcard to the contacts, but this method is out of date and I can't find a way to add VCard / website to Contact / website. How to write the current method to add a Vcard to the contacts?

```cs
public void SaveContacts(
    string name, string number, string email, string
    company, string jobtitle, string postal, string website)
{
    var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionInsert);
    intent.SetType(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentType);
    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Name, name);
    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Phone, number);
    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Email, email);
    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Company, company);
    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.JobTitle, jobtitle);
    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Postal, postal);
    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Notes, website);

    activity.StartActivity(intent);
    Toast.MakeText(activity, "ContactSaved", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the following code,and it could add a contact with multiple phone numbers in android. It works on my side.

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public  string TAG
        {
            get
            {
                return "MainActivity";
            }
        }
        static readonly int REQUEST_CONTACTS = 1;

        static string[] PERMISSIONS_CONTACT = {
            Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts,
            Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts
        };

        Button button;

        View  layout;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            layout = FindViewById(Resource.Id.root_layout);

        }

        public void NewContact(ref List<ContentProviderOperation> ops, string displayName, string Number1, string Number2, string Number3, string Number4)
        {
            ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder =
                ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ContentUri);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.InterfaceConsts.AccountType, null);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, null);
            ops.Add(builder.Build());

            //Name  
            builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
            builder.WithValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, 0);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype,
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.ContentItemType);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DisplayName, displayName);
            //builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GivenName, firstName);  
            ops.Add(builder.Build());

            //Number1  
            builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
            builder.WithValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, 0);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype,
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentItemType);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, Number1);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type,
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.TypeCustom);
            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Data2, (int)PhoneDataKind.Mobile);

            ops.Add(builder.Build());
            //Number2  
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Number2))
            {
                builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
                builder.WithValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, 0);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype,
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentItemType);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, Number2);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type,
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.TypeCustom);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Data2, (int)PhoneDataKind.Mobile);
                ops.Add(builder.Build());
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Number3))
            {
                builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
                builder.WithValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, 0);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype,
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentItemType);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, Number3);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type,
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.TypeCustom);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Data2, (int)PhoneDataKind.Mobile);
                ops.Add(builder.Build());
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Number4))
            {
                builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
                builder.WithValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, 0);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype,
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentItemType);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, Number4);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type,
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.TypeCustom);
                builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Data2, (int)PhoneDataKind.Mobile);
                ops.Add(builder.Build());
            }

        }

        /*
        public void SaveContacts(string filename)
        {
            var documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath.AbsolutePath, filename);
            var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            List<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new List<ContentProviderOperation>();

            foreach (var strLine in fileContent)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strLine))
                    continue;
                var array = strLine.Split(new string[] { "\t", ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

               // NewContact(...);

                //Add the new contact  
                ContentProviderResult[] res;
                res = ContentResolver.ApplyBatch(ContactsContract.Authority, ops);
                ops.Clear();
            }
        }

        */
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
             if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACTS)
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "Received response for contact permissions request.");

                // We have requested multiple permissions for contacts, so all of them need to be
                // checked.
                if (PermissionUtil.VerifyPermissions(grantResults))
                {
                    // All required permissions have been granted, display contacts fragment.
                    Snackbar.Make(layout, Resource.String.permission_available_contacts, Snackbar.LengthShort).Show();

                    // save contact
                    saveContact();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Info(TAG, "Contacts permissions were NOT granted.");
                    Snackbar.Make(layout, Resource.String.permissions_not_granted, Snackbar.LengthShort).Show();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }


        [Export]
        public void SaveContacts(View v)
        {
            Log.Info(TAG, "Show contacts button pressed. Checking permissions.");

            // Verify that all required contact permissions have been granted.
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts) != (int)Permission.Granted
                || ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                // Contacts permissions have not been granted.
                Log.Info(TAG, "Contact permissions has NOT been granted. Requesting permissions.");
                RequestContactsPermissions();
            }
            else
            {
                // Contact permissions have been granted. Show the contacts fragment.
                Log.Info(TAG, "Contact permissions have already been granted. Displaying contact details.");

                //Add the new contact

                saveContact();
            }
        }


        void RequestContactsPermissions()
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts)
                || ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts))
            {

                // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
                // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
                // For example, if the request has been denied previously.
                Log.Info(TAG, "Displaying contacts permission rationale to provide additional context.");

                // Display a SnackBar with an explanation and a button to trigger the request.
                Snackbar.Make(layout, Resource.String.permission_contacts_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LengthIndefinite).SetAction(Resource.String.ok, new Action<View>(delegate (View obj) {
                        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_CONTACT, REQUEST_CONTACTS);
                    })).Show();

            }
            else
            {
                // Contact permissions have not been granted yet. Request them directly.
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_CONTACT, REQUEST_CONTACTS);
            }
        }


        public void saveContact() {
            List<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new List<ContentProviderOperation>();
            NewContact(ref ops, "test", "1234", "2234", "3234", "4234");

            //Add the new contact
            ContentProviderResult[] res;
            try
            {
                res = ContentResolver.ApplyBatch(ContactsContract.Authority, ops);
                ops.Clear();//Add this line   
                Toast.MakeText(this, "contact saved !", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("**************-----------> : " + e.Message);
                Toast.MakeText(this, "contact not saved_message !", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

class `PermissionUtil`

```
public abstract  class PermissionUtil
{
    public static bool VerifyPermissions(Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        // At least one result must be checked.
        if (grantResults.Length < 1)
            return false;

        // Verify that each required permission has been granted, otherwise return false.
        foreach (Permission result in grantResults)
        {
            if (result != Permission.Granted)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

layout `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
        android:onClick="SaveContacts"
        android:text="save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:**

1.Rembember to add the following permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

And an app that targets Android 6.0 must always perform a runtime permission check.

For more details, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows

2.add reference `Mono.Android.Export`;

3.You can refer official sample: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android-m/RuntimePermissions .

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to implement this. I've already added the permissions, but I'll definitely read your link for more information.

Comment: Ok, so if I have understood correctly, I must first check whether the authorization has been granted by the user before accessing the contacts. So the authorization in the Android Manifesto is not enough ???. Sorry, I'm new to mobile development;)

Comment: Hi  @KarsaOrlong1981,  I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks again:) I have now tried to implement your code. I answered my question again to show my attempt, unfortunately, ContentProviderResult [] res; gives always null back. I don't find the fault.

Comment: Could you please post your demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: https://github.com/KarsaOrlong1981/QR_CodeScanAndGen/commit/2d58e55298e5f569a255fd1e7e6b79c0147226f8 I implemented it all in the MainActivity.cs now it works but how can i use this from my ScannerPage.cs at the moment the Scanner recognizes an Contact QR-Code? I know i'm annoying you but i'm really grateful for your help. This is my first real project with Xamarin.forms
and I get all the information about it from documentation, unfortunately most of the documentaries are out of date.

Comment: Hi @KarsaOrlong1981,congratulations on successfully implementing this .

Answer (score 0):

1.I've now found a way to add the runtime permissions:

```
      public async Task GetContactAsync()
    {
        var status = await CheckAndRequestPermissionAsync(new Permissions.ContactsWrite());
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Permission for Contacts denied.", "The last time you refused the authorization to access the Contacts.Give this app the authorization for your Contacts to add Contacts directly via a QR-Code.", "OK.");
            Navigation.RemovePage(this);
            return;
        }

        //Add vcard to contacts
        SaveContacts(vCardName, vCardTel, vCardEmail, vCardORG, vCardTitle, vCardAdress, vCardURL);
        Navigation.RemovePage(this);
    }

    public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestPermissionAsync<T>(T permission)
                where T : BasePermission
    {
        var status = await permission.CheckStatusAsync();
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            status = await permission.RequestAsync();
        }

        return status;
    }
```